# Use JS Modules to return elements vs. return a function which created the elements

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing The Odin Project and my current project involves adding elements to the HTML using JS. The webpage should be tabbed with each tab being drawn using a separate JS module. In the instructions [here](https://www.theodinproject.com/lessons/node-path-javascript-restaurant-page), they say

> Each module will export a function that creates a div element, adds the appropriate content and styles to that element and then appends it to the DOM.

As I worked through the project, I felt that I could instead create the elements in the module and have the module export the elements themselves (instead of a function) which are then appended in the main script.

My approach (simplified):

```js
// menu.js
const menu = document.createElement('div');
/* add children to menu */

export default menu;
```

```js
// index.js
import menu from './menu.js'

const content = document.querySelector('#content')

content.appendChild(menu)
```

**Compared to the suggestion in the project, what are the advantages and disadvantages of each method?**

Also if you use a function as suggested, does that mean that we would need to pass the parent element into the function since its not initialized within the module?

Edit: Also, I could be misinterpreting their suggestion where instead of having the function append the elements to the main content element, I should instead have the function return an element similar to my approach, just enclosed in a function à la functional programming.

Answer (score 0):

In my personal experience it depends on how modular you want the module to be. A menu you may want to have a very similar layout throughout the application. However with something like a modal popup you may want to have the module return a skeleton which you can then populate with an element in your `index.js`.

You also may want to consider how uniform the structure of your modules are if you intend to reuse them or have someone else work the same modules - in this case I'd think it better that most/all the modules behave in a similar fashion.

Personally, my modules have a snippet of html you add to the body of the page(a one liner like a div) and a js import to interact with the module which will use that html div to do what it needs to do.